# Query table in DQL to get records created in the past week

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, timestamp, doctrine-1.2

I'm trying to write a query in Doctrine that will return records added within a certain numbr of days, I have this line in my query but doesn't work as expected:

```
$q->andWhere('g.date_added >= ?', array(strtotime('-'.$recent_interval.' day')));
```

date_added is a mySQL timestamp.

recent_interval is number of days.

I am using Doctrine-1.2.4 with Zend Framework 1.11.7

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format of a **MySQL timestamp** is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. You're comparing it with a **UNIX timestamp** which is a number returned from [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime).

You need to convert the UNIX timestamp into a MySQL timestamp first to make it work.

To format a UNIX timestamp, you can make use of the PHP [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function. The format is `Y-m-d H:i:s`.

Example:

```
$compare = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-'.$recent_interval.' day'));
$q->andWhere('g.date_added >= ?', array($compare));
```

Answer (score 1):

You've forgotten to change the array to something Doctrine understands:

The following shows you what to do:

> ->andWhere('g.date_added >= ?', date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-2 weeks")))

Comment: Obviously you would want to do: strtotime('-'.$recent_interval.' day') instead of my -2 weeks example.